# Android how to pass data related to a listview item from sqlite database into next activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, listactivity

i need to pass data from database to the next activity which this data is in the same row as the selected item. I have tried to do it but, it shows all data in the listview. I need to show the title in the listview items and the description in the next activity.
Here is my code:

```
package com.example.assfar.travel_guide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.assfar.R;
import com.example.assfar.database.DBHelper;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TravelGuide extends ListActivity {

    private DBHelper dataBase;
    private List<String> guide_title_list= new ArrayList<String>();
    private Cursor cursor;
    String title;
    Integer id;
    String desc;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travelguide);

        dataBase=  DBHelper.instance();
        SQLiteDatabase db= dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

        cursor= db.rawQuery("select * from Tour_Guide", null);

        if(cursor!=null) {
             if(cursor.moveToFirst());
             {
                 do
                {

                  desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tour_Description"));
                  title= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("guide_title")); 
                  id= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                  guide_title_list.add("" + title +id +desc );


                 } while(cursor.moveToNext());

             }
                 }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, guide_title_list));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

       //String selectedItem= ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

       String selectedValue= (String) getListAdapter(). getItem(position);

       Intent i = new Intent(TravelGuide.this, Travel_Guide_Details.class);

        i.putExtra("selected item", selectedValue);


        startActivity(i);

        }

}
```

and the next activity code:

```
package com.example.assfar.travel_guide;

import com.example.assfar.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Travel_Guide_Details extends Activity {

    public static  Cursor cursor;
    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel_guide_details);

        //tour guide description in text view
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.guide_desc);

        Intent i= getIntent();

        // getting attached intent data
        String item = i.getStringExtra("selected item");

        // displaying selected product name
        textView.setText(item);

         } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Take a field of type HashMap

```
HashMap<String,String> details=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

And in your FirstActivity

also Add values to HashMap like this

```
    desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tour_Description"));
    title= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("guide_title")); 
    id= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    guide_title_list.add("" + title +id +desc );
    details.put("" + title +id +desc,title+desc);
```

And in your ItemClick get value like this

```
 String selectedValue= (String) getListAdapter(). getItem(position);
   String itemTitleDesc=details.get(selectedValue);
```

And pass

```
 i.putExtra("selected item", itemTitleDesc);
```

Comment: how can i pass a photo to the next activity?